# Simple React issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having trouble with a little snippet of js, I keep getting the error:

Failed to compile
./src/App.js
  Line 81:9:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

```
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Code is as follows:

```
function TaskList() {
  const deadlines = [
    { title: "wash the dishes!"},
    { title: "take out the trash!" },
    { title: "walk the dog!"},
  ];

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "30px" }}>
      {deadlines.map((task) => {
        <>
          <a>{task.title}</a>
        </>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `return` your JSX snippet in the `map` callback:

```
function TaskList() {
  const deadlines = [
    { title: "wash the dishes!"},
    { title: "take out the trash!" },
    { title: "walk the dog!"},
  ];

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "30px" }}>
      {deadlines.map((task) => {
        return (
          <>
            <a>{task.title}</a>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the jsx from inside the map method.

```
function TaskList() {
  const deadlines = [
    { title: "wash the dishes!"},
    { title: "take out the trash!" },
    { title: "walk the dog!"},
  ];

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "30px" }}>
      {deadlines.map((task) => {
        return ( // return the jsx
         <>
           <a>{task.title}</a>
         </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```